# Is there any API so we could handle iOS persistent push notification via code (Objective-C or Swift)?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Programmatically, I want to create/set persistent push notification in iOS.
It can be manageable in iOS11 manually from notification settings. But I want to do it programmatically using Objective-C or Swift.

Comment: What’s a *persistent* push notification? Also push notifications need to be send from a server. Not really sure I understand your question...

Comment: Persistent Notification: They don't disappear automatically, so you can take your time to act on them without worrying about the banner fading away

Comment: Ajay, I think it is a setting the user has to select in the push notification settings of an app in the system settings. Go to Device Settings -> App -> Notifications -> Select "Persistent". I am not aware of a setting, where you can force this behavior for users.

Comment: Thanks, I want to achieve this programmatically.

Comment: This is a legitimate question.  Can we make a change programmatically to the settings that the user can from the Settings App ?